# What Can I Do If My Joint Operations App/Game Is Rejected Due to Incorrect Provider Name in HMS Core (APK) Update?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

When I submitted my game, which has HMS Core capabilities integrated, for review, it was rejected due to incorrect provider name during HMS Core (APK) update.

I use Android Studio and I can't find any solutions for this problem in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be manually configured for HMS Core (APK) updates for version 4.0 and later.

The provider name is automatically configured in the manifest file after game packaging. To check whether the configuration exists, You need to decompile the game package and check whether the following configurations exist under the application element in the manifest file:

```
<provider  
    android:name="com.huawei.hms.update.provider.UpdateProvider"  
    <!-- Replace xxx.xxx.xxx with the actual game package name. -->  
    android:authorities="xxx.xxx.xxx.hms.update.provider"  
    android:exported="false"  
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >  
</provider>

<provider
    android:name="com.huawei.updatesdk.fileprovider.UpdateSdkFileProvider"
    <!-- Replace xxx.xxx.xxx with the actual game package name. -->
    android:authorities="xxx.xxx.xxx.updateSdk.fileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
</provider>
```

If the configurations do not exist, packaging errors or other exceptions may have occurred. In this case, you would need to manually add the provider name.